# Eclipse and clip board

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse is there a provision to copy multiple items and then paste the items selectively from the clip board? IntelliJ has this feature and I used to find it very useful. Does Eclipse have this and if so what is the key board short cut to view items in the clip board?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [multi-clipboard plugin](http://www.eclipse-plugins.info/eclipse/plugin_details.jsp?id=930) to do just that.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I do not need the fancy support of copying the contents into a file while closing and stuff like that. I just need the basic clip board copy past stuff. It is not natively supported in Eclipse?

Comment: Linux has it, a native clipboard system level. Handy to invoke, I think Ctrl+Alt+V, unlike IntelliJ where its Ctrl+Shift+V. But that would be completely different - may be unfamiliar - territory for you.

Comment: I read up on the linux clipboard thing and it says that you have to install application to do that (separate for gnome and kde). Are you sure of the system level thing and if can you please point me some more info?

Comment: @Abhi, Eclipse does not have native support for such a clipboard. Installing pugins to extend Eclipse's functionality is a very normal thing to do. Any particular reason why you are not in favor of installing this plugin ? Even though it has fancy features, it still does the basic job of providing multiple clipboards.

Comment: @Rahul, I do not want to install plugins as too many plugins make eclipse dead slow and grouchy to deal with..So I am trying to avoid..If that is the only way to move forward then be it..

Comment: I love multi-clipboard, but it doesn't appear to work with Juno or Kepler. It doesn't appear to be maintained anymore either.

Answer (score 1):

You may check [More Clipboard](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/more-clipboard#.UdULNz6GXQo) plugin. It's less complicated than Multi Clipboard and just works.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a system-wide clipboard manager, like the great **[Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/)** (for Windows)